# Que signifie « par trois » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, nombres

La phrase dont je parle est « Ils s'en vont par trois », et il y s'agit des trois mousquetaires, je crois.

Voila [le contexte](http://samedidefi.canalblog.com/archives/2010/05/08/17821837.html).

> Ils s'en vont par trois
>   Les mousquetaires du roi
>   Louis 1 et 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit ici d'un texte écrit par un humoriste dans lequel il ne faut pas chercher de sens. La rime et le jeu de mot priment sur le sens.

« Par trois » est à prendre au sens propre, c'est à dire : en groupes de trois unités.

Si on veut un explication logique on peut soit ne voir aucune référence aux trois mousquetaires, soit, si tu veux en voir une, on peut dire que les trois mousquetaires (qui en réalité sont quatre) + Louis 1 + Louis 3, ça fait 6 personnes en tout ; ils s'en vont par trois, c'est à dire qu'ils s'en vont en deux groupes de trois personnes chacun. On peut aussi dire que l'auteur dit que les mousquetaires vont par trois en référence implicite aux trois mousquetaires.

Comment: J'avoue ne pas trop comprendre la complexité de ta réponse. Le deuxième paragraphe me paraît suffisant : "par trois" = "à trois", "en groupe de trois", "tous les trois". Je n'y vois pas d'humour ou de référence.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Je pense que celui qui a posé la question comprenait « par trois » et sa mention des 3 mousquetaires pouvait faire croire qu'il cherchait un sens caché.

Answer (score 3):

À l'instar de l'expression « deux par deux », souvent utilisée dans les cours de récréation par les instituteurs pour demander aux enfants de se ranger avant d'entrer en classe.

L'auteur veut ici dire qu'ils se déplacent et agissent toujours par groupe de 3.